# How to import .cer public key into java trust store?

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption, keytool, java-security

Here is the command that I am using to import the public key into my trust store.

```
$ keytool -import -trustcacerts -file dev.cer -alias my_alias -keystore truststore.jks -storepass mypass -v
```

The output that I get is:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.addTrustedCert(Main.java:2652)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1006)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:340)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:333)
```

The content of the `dev.cer` file looks like:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
... encoded text ...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

One more thing worth mentioning that this certificate was generated on Windows running machine and I want to import it in the Linux environemnt. Maybe it has something to do with the special characters.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should't you be importing a certificate to your trust store? A certificate has `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `----END CERTIFICATE-----`.

Comment: Do you mean I have to import my public key into a keystore instead of the truststore?

Comment: I get exactly the same outcome if I run the following command:
$ keytool -import -alias my_alias -file dev.cer -keystore keystore.jks -storepass mypass -v

Comment: No.  I mean the file you have is not a certificate, it's a public key.  You need a certificate in order to import to a trust store.

Comment: What's the proper format of the file must be? Can I convert public key into a certificate and then import it into truststore/keystore?

Comment: Ihor , do not have the full context here , keytool -keystore cacerts -importcert -alias my_alias -file dev.cer -storepass changeit -v , what does this return ?

Comment: Avery certificate contains a public key but a public key itself can not be converted into a certificate. Where did you get the key from?

Comment: I'm coding an API, that will require requests to contain an Authorization header containing a bearer token to be generated by the requestor.    The token will be a JSON Web Token (JWT) signed with a private key.  I'm going to decrypt the bearer token using the corresponding public key and validate the contents.
A company that plans to invoke my API sent me dev.cer file with the content described above. I wanted to import their public key into my keystore.

Comment: @RamachandranGA it returns:
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.addTrustedCert(Main.java:2652)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1006)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:340)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:333)

Comment: Then the company that plans to invoke your API sent you a public key instead of a certificate.  You cannot import the key into your trust store - you need a certificate for that.  You can either ask for a certificate or write code to decrypt the bearer token with the public key directly.

Comment: I think this answers my question! Thank you @garethTheRed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate` is caused by the fact that instead of importing a certificate, there was an attempt to import a public key (even though the file extension is `.cer` , the header `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and the footer `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----` indicate that the file doesn't contain a valid certificate, but the public key only). Terms public certificate and public key at times by mistake are used interchangeably.